# Android dimens resources selection

Tags: android

I am a bit confused how android decides what resources to choose. I have the following folders with the following files:

```
--
 |-values
     |-dimens.xml
 |-values-hdpi
     |-dimens.xml
 |-values-land
     |-dimens.xml
```

And the files content is the following:

First:

```
 <resources>
        <dimen name="data_dimen1">1dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="data_dimen2">1dp</dimen>
 </resources>
```

Second:

```
 <resources>
        <dimen name="data_dimen1">2dp</dimen>
 </resources>
```

Third:

```
 <resources>
        <dimen name="data_dimen2">4dp</dimen>
 </resources>
```

I have a device HDPI and in landscape. What will be data_dimen2 and data_dimen1 values?

Comment: `values-land` is for **mdpi** devices. You want to add a `values-hdpi-land` folder with an appropriate `dimens.xml` file.

Comment: Moreover, the resources should have the **same name** in different densities.

Answer (score 0):

data_dimen1 will be used. because values-land is for mdpi devices.

Comment: It's clear that data_dimen1 will be used, the question is what value will it have